# Is it possible to exclude IDE packages from requirements.txt with pip freeze?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip

I use Visual Studio Code with its python plugins.
But I don't want these linter packages will be added to requirements.txt file.

Is it possible?

***EDIT:***

***Explanation with an example:***
The venv has three packages: *django*, *requests*, *some_linter_package_for_vs_code*.
When I run `pip freeze >> requirements.txt` I want to avoid adding *some_linter_package_for_vs_code* to the requirements.txt file

Comment: You could try something like [_pip-tools_](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/)

Answer (score -1):

pipe the result of `pip freeze` to `grep -v`

```
pip freeze | grep -v linterPackage | grep -v otherPackage > requirements.txt
```

Be aware that the linter package depends on other packages and that some of your needed packages might also depend on them.

To find out which packages the linter depends on start a new virtual environment and only install the linter and get a `pip freeze > lint.txt` to see which packages you might need to filter off.

Maybe write a python script that will use the content of `lint.txt` to filter the result:

```
pip freeze | myFilterScript lint.txt > requirements.txt
```